# how to calculate exponential power of a number in ant script

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I need to calculate the exponential power of a number.

This is the code I have tried:

```
<math result="result" datatype="int" >
 <op op="*">
  <num value="2" datatype="int" />
  <op op="pow">
     <num value="2" datatype="int" />
     <num value="2" datatype="int" />
  </op>
 </op>
</math>
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error: [math] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.sf.antcontrib.math.Math.pow(jav
>   a.lang.String, boolean, [Lnet.sf.antcontrib.math.Evaluateable;)

Comment: Do you have `<taskdef>` in your build.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The "math" task you're using is an external [ant-contrib task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/math_task.html).

To do this using standard ANT requires an embedded script. For example, the following prints the result "64"

```
  <target name="build">

    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
      project.setProperty("result", Math.pow(4, 3));
    ]]></script>

    <echo message="${result}"/>
  </target>
```